# heroku using gulp - no error in logs - still

Tags: heroku, gulp

I am trying to setup heroku deploy using gulp...

> 2015-05-31T12:39:43.160121+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:39:43] Webserver
>   started at http://localhost:24018
>
> 2015-05-31T12:39:43.208954+00:00
>   app[web.1]: [12:39:43] Finished 'serve' after 544 ms
>
> 2015-05-31T12:40:39.255239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot
>   timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of
>   launch
>
> 2015-05-31T12:40:39.255427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping
>   process with SIGKILL

as per the logs webserver does get started successfully at given port.. below is how I am getting

```
 port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
```

so is there any other port heroku expects application start or is there a way one can know which port heroku is checking??

note : the app does starts successfully if I do `forman start web`, so what can be the issue here?? though `forman` starts the application at a port 5000. I tried to hardcore port to 5000 but still got the same error as above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was i am using gulp-webserver which defaults to localhost, just need to change that to `host: '0.0.0.0'`

```
gulp.task('heroku', ['wiredep','inject'], function () {
  return gulp.src(config.base)
    .pipe(plugins.webserver({
        host: '0.0.0.0', 
        port: process.env.PORT,
        livereload: false,
        open: false
    }));
});
```